# How to decompress a compressed type audio file using ffmpeg?

Tags: objective-c, ios, audio, ffmpeg

I need to decompress an audio file through code using ffmpeg.
I have compiled FFMPEG for iOS with the link: http://lists.mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2009-October/076618.html

Now I am not getting how to include ffmpeg in my xcode project? Which ffmpeg libraries to use?
Which methods to use for decompresson?

Please answer.

Comment: Easy tutorial: https://rodic.fr/blog/libavcodec-tutorial-decode-virtually-any-audio-file/

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

http://www.inb.uni-luebeck.de/~boehme/using_libavcodec.html

Answer (score 0):

More ffmpeg tutorials:

http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/ffmpegtutorial_all.html
https://github.com/mpenkov/ffmpeg-tutorial

> Now I am not getting how to include ffmpeg in my xcode project?
>   Which ffmpeg libraries to use?

You need to add next libs to your project: libavcodec.a, libavformat.a.
If you plan use resampling audio add: libswresample.a.
And add ffmpeg folder to 'User header search paths' in build settings.

> Which methods to use for decompresson?

for decoding: `avcodec_decode_audio4`
for resampling: `swr_convert`